# Parse JSON using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit, jsonp

I want to use retrofit to retrive some data, but I have strange api. My JSON starts with brackets. Something like this:

```
({"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    }});
```

Im using Retrofit, and when I try to call `call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>()` I cant get response. Of course I have and error from

`public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());`

`D/Error: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $`

It`s because my JSON is valid, but I cant parse it. Where and how can I modify it, deleting brackets? Thanks

Comment: you need to remove "(" from start and ");" from end .

Comment: any easy way to handle this when I get a data from URL?

Comment: i have trick for that , just clear me this is only response, you got when i fired any request to backend ?

Comment: @kdblue exactly

Comment: cool then , just take response in string and use String replace method try, asked if you have any problem  .

Comment: @kdblue Actually, how can I do that, I haveve tried `String response = interface.getResponse().execute().body().toString()`, of course I get JsonSyntaxException. I cant get body without executing it

Comment: try to use JsonObject , (its not JSONObject ) instead of Response.

Answer (score 0):

I have The same issue before.

Of course The best way to solve your problem is to ask your backend team to eliminate the brackets from the response but here is another workaround solutions if you don't have access to your backend creator :

What i did is to accept this malformed JSON as String and remove the first and the last brackets
Then re-transform it to JSONObject and parse it using Gson.

Also you can accept this as type Object and with some workarounds you can extract your JSONObject.